# Select a value from a dependent drop down list

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

How can you select a value from a drop down list when there is no option values to choose from?

This is my code to set attribute to three 3 web forms drop down lists.     The first one suceedss.

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("provincia")-
.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 21)

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("canton")-
.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 1)

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("parroquia")-
.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 1)
```

This is the HTML code for the 3 drop down lists:

```
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
for="provincia">Provincia *</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" 
data-val-required="El campo Provincia * es obligatorio." id="provincia" 
name="provincia"><option value="">Seleccionar una provincia</option>
<option value="01">AZUAY</option>
<option value="02">BOLIVAR</option>
<option value="03">CA&#209;AR</option>
<option value="04">CARCHI</option>
<option value="06">CHIMBORAZO</option>
<option value="05">COTOPAXI</option>
<option value="07">EL ORO</option>
<option value="08">ESMERALDAS</option>
<option value="20">GALAPAGOS</option>
<option value="09">GUAYAS</option>
<option value="10">IMBABURA</option>
<option value="11">LOJA</option>
<option value="12">LOS RIOS</option>
<option value="13">MANABI</option>
<option value="14">MORONA SANTIAGO</option>
<option value="15">NAPO</option>
<option value="22">ORELLANA</option>
<option value="16">PASTAZA</option>
<option value="17">PICHINCHA</option>
<option value="24">SANTA ELENA</option>
<option value="23">SANTO DOMINGO DE LOS TSACHILAS</option>
<option value="21">SUCUMBIOS</option>
<option value="18">TUNGURAHUA</option>
<option value="19">ZAMORA CHINCHIPE</option>
<option value="90">ZONAS NO DELIMITADAS</option>
</select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
for="canton">Cant&#243;n *</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" id="canton" 
name="canton"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
for="parroquia">Parroquia *</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control" id="parroquia" 
name="parroquia"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have succeeded at assigning value to "provincia", however I am not anywhere near that degree of success with "canton" and "parroquia". The error message I get from the website simply says that "canton" and "parroquia" are mandatory. My guess is that there is no line in both  "canton" and "parroquia".